# Can Minecraft BE commands be converted to JE commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to remake/translate a Bedrock Edition command into Java Edition, but it's not working:

```
/execute @e[type=!armor_stand] ~ ~ ~ tp ^ ^ ^0.10 facing @e[name=blackhole,r=10]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you want the command to do?

Comment: While I'm answering your question, you should explain what you expect your command to do in JE and what, specifically, is not working once translated. It'll improve the quality of your post, and leave less information for inference. Plus, you'll get a faster and more accurate answer. :)

Comment: Your command has been translated in my answer. Enjoy. :)

Answer (score 5):

***TL;DR**: The short answer: ***yes** and **no***. Jump to the **Your Use-Case** section for the translated version of your command.*

---

### Direct Translation

I'd like to start with the shortest explanation that there are ***some*** commands that ***cannot*** be ***directly*** converted to Java edition, [per the documentation](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands) on commands. Here is a sample of the command table that shows a few of the first commands that ***cannot*** be directly used in Java edition:

| Command | Description | BE | JE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `/ability` | Grants or revokes a player ability. | Yes | No |
| `/alwaysday` | An alias of `/daylock`. Locks and unlocks the day-night cycle. | Yes | No |
| `/camerashake` | Used to enable a camera shaking effect. | Yes | No |

<sub>***Note**: Please refer to the aforementioned documentation for the complete table.*</sub>

However, there are some commands that have very, very similar syntax in both Bedrock edition and Java edition. For example, the [`fill` command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/fill) is one such candidate for nearly direct translation:

> Java Edition
>
> ```
> fill <from> <to> <block> [destroy|hollow|keep|outline|replace]
> ```
>
> Bedrock Edition
>
> ```
> fill <from: x y z> <to: x y z> <tileName: Block> [tileData: int] [oldBlockHandling: FillMode]
> ```

As a result, the following command ***should*** execute successfully in currently released versions of Bedrock and Java editions:

```
fill ~ ~ ~ ~5 ~5 ~5 concrete
```

---

### Indirect Translation (Your Use-Case)

The `execute` command is one of those commands that is incredibly powerful in Java edition, but limited in Bedrock edition. Based on the command you provided:

```
/execute @e[type=!armor_stand] ~ ~ ~ tp ^ ^ ^0.10 facing @e[name=blackhole,r=10]
```

I can infer some guidelines for translation:

> **All entities** that are **not** of type `armor_stand`, from their **current location**, **execute** a **teleport** command to their **local coordinates** plus `0.10` on the **z-axis**, *facing* **all entities** named **blackhole** within a **radius** of `10`.

In Java edition, your command is a bit more complicated than it seems, and Bedrock edition is notorious for hiding this from us. To get your command to work, you'll need to run the command as the entity, at the entity's location, facing the target:

```
/execute as x at x facing entity x eyes run tp...
```

Subsequently, your full command in Java edition is:

```
/execute as @e[type=!armor_stand] at @s facing entity @e[name=blackhole,r=10] eyes run tp ^ ^ ^0.10
```

<sub>***Note**: The use of `@s` after the `at` is enabled by the fact that the `as` has already established the entity we need and since we are executing the command *as* the entity, we can use the self target.*</sub>

Comment: Note that (in your last command) after you've done [as @e[...]] you can do [at @s] later on to refer to this very same entity, rather than rewriting the entity selector.

Comment: I think it's safer to do `tp @s ^ ^ ^0.10` to ensure the correct entity is teleported.  I may be wrong on that since it's been a long while since I last played around with commands.